# How can I access current size properties of a d3 svg chart in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've made a responsive layout with bootstrap for 2 columns, and my left column has a d3 force-layout chart.

Previously I was using a fixed size, and with it was calculating a constant used by another function to ensure nodes have sensible placement on the chart (a solution I found here on stack):

```
var w = 400,
    h = 400,
    r = 6,
    k = Math.sqrt(nodes.length / (w * h)),
    fill = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .gravity(100 * k).charge(-10 / k)
    .linkDistance(30)
    .nodes(nodes).links(links)
    .start();
```

Now that I have a responsive layout, I can't use `w` and `h`. Rather I need some some sort of getter to see the current `width` and `height` of the chart so I can calculate my constant.

I'm new to Javascript code so this is the best I came up with by exploring the console:

```
d3.select("#chart").property('height')['animVal']['value']
d3.select("#chart").property('width')['animVal']['value']
```

Is this how I should be doing this? Is there a more direct function? This seems ugly to me..

Comment: Isn't that something that you can reach easily through getBBox() or getBoundingClientRect()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the rest of your code, but typically, you would use [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect). This function returns a read only object containing the location and the width and the height of the selected element. In your case, you could use it like this:

```
d3.select("#chart").getBoundingClientRect().height
d3.select("#chart").getBoundingClientRect().width
```

Comment: Awesome that is much cleaner. Is this like a general Javascript thing or part of d3? I don't normally do web stuff so I am totally out of my element.

Comment: Fortunately,  `getBoundingClientRect()` is a general JavaScript function that can be called on an `element`. In the example, the element was selected using d3, but it is also possible to use native code to access the element. That would look like this:
`document.getElementById('chart').getBoundingClientRect()`

Comment: That is very helpful. Thank you!